# Odoo Server Error when try to access to accounting app

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 on my local debian jessie server. I installed without demo data, and installed basic apps (like accounting, sales, crm, others)

After installation and I configured odoo as non root user all was OK.

I was see the options available, and can access to accounting app but when I restarted my computer and start odoo server again and try to open accounting app I get the errors bellow.

Anyone know how can I resolve that?

Thanks!

**Odoo Server Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/http.py", line 680, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/http.py", line 316, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/http.py", line 959, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/http.py", line 509, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 892, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 884, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 354, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/web_planner/models/web_planner.py", line 45, in render
    return self.env['ir.ui.view'].browse(template_id).render(values=values)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 574, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 29, in render
    return super(view, self).render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, values=values, engine=engine, context=context)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1070, in render
    return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 252, in render
    element = self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 172, in get_template
    document = qwebcontext.loader(name)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1068, in loader
    return self.read_template(cr, uid, name, context=context)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 943, in read_template
    return self._read_template(cr, uid, view_id, context=context)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in _read_template
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 928, in _read_template
    arch = self.read_combined(cr, uid, view_id, fields=['arch'], context=context)['arch']
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/no_root/odoo-9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 640, in read_combined
    view_arch = etree.fromstring(view['arch'].encode('utf-8'))
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3092, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:70691)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1828, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106689)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1716, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105478)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1086, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:100105)
  File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94543)
  File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96003)
  File "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:95050)
XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'aacute' not defined, line 549, column 76
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an error within the translations in the language you use.

Most likely, the mistakes have already been corrected. Then, all you have to do is:

- Update your Odoo server, by installing the latest all-in-one package, or pulling the latest revision from the Odoo repository on Github,
- Loading again the language, making sure to check [`Overwrite existing terms`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUDIE.png), in `Settings` -> `Translations` -> `Load a translation`.

Notice:

- You currently have to be in [debugger mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6rM6.png) to see this checkbox
- If you wrote custom translations, this can overwrite them

If this doesn't solve your issue, this is likely there are still mistakes within the translations of your language. You can then contact the Odoo support by email (online@odoo.com).

Comment: Thanks! But after do your suggestions the error continue. translations? I test with default english and the error continue.

Comment: Well, if it happens while being in English (US, not other ones), then it's a problem within one of your view architecture. Looks for `aacute` in the views architecture (there is a filter to do, in Settings > Technical > User Interface > Views).